# Is it possible to group templates into namespaces in meteor?

Tags: meteor

is there any solution to group templates into namespaces?

while testing some example codes i came to the question, how to handle name conflicts in huge ammounts of templates. for example lets say i have an application with three parts:

- users (templates: login,logout reset_password and settings)
- forum (templates: new_post, list_posts, view_post, search)
- products (templates: order,view,details,search)

with two different search templates in products and forum i would get in trouble. this can be solved by just name them forum_search and products_search, but it would feel more natural to do it the namespace way.

instead of access with:

```
template.forum_search
template.products_search
```

doing somthing like this:

```
template.forum.search
template.products.search
```

Comment: This is a pretty common complaint, and I haven't really come up with a good solution myself. The best I've managed is the same as your solution. The Meteor devs are aware of the problem and will eventually be offering a solution of some sort. For more info, check [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/meteor-talk/namespacing/meteor-talk/b14uQQ-8Ri8/djB8iJ0HOX4J)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this directly at the moment, but it's on the Meteor roadmap for version 1.0: https://trello.com/card/template-and-helper-namespacing/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/17